# Running 2 feature files in a Maven project by changing goals in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, cucumber-jvm

I need to run my features file separately using different goals or tags in pom.xml. So whenever I set one goal respective feature files should run. If there are multiple ways we can achieve this I would appreciate the answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pom.xml isn't the right vehicle. Take a look at [Tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags).